# The use of “booked”

Tags: word-usage

Situation: I’d like to have a haircut with a hairdresser named Lucy. Is it correct to say “I’ll have Lucy booked for my haircut next Tuesday?”

Thank you.

Comment: You would need to include what you found for a definition and sample usage sentences from at least one dictionary.

Comment: There are contexts where that sentence could be fine, but if you're asking what to say when you call the salon to make the appointment, no, don't say that. Please clarify how you want to use the sentence.

Comment: I see. It happened when I was paying for my hairdo at the till and I talked to the reception. I actually said I’ll have a haircut with Lucy next Tuesday. But the word “booked” just came up in my mind. As a learner of English, I’m wondering if the sentence “I’ll have Lucy booked” is okay to use. Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion it's not right - and certainly not idiomatic - when making a *new* booking, but it would still be understood. On the other hand if you have a regular appointment and you just want to (re)confirm the next one then that sentence in an enquiring tone is fine. Or if there is a booking but there is some doubt about whether it will be with Lucy or another stylist.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's better to just ask for clarification than to answer in comments. You're doing both. Rose might be satisfied with your reply and not upvote or accept any good answers. Also, if what you say is wrong, no-one can downvote it, they can only reply to your comment which could get missed.